# Problem in Elasticsearch query with sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Below is the my elastic document.

```
{
  "_index": "records",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "27",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "dlvehicleclass": "dlVehicleClass",
    "challan_offences": [
      {
        "offence_name": "Valid Insurance",
        "amount": 100
      },
      {
        "offence_name": "Fail to produce certificate of Fitness",
        "amount": 4000
      },
      {
        "offence_name": "Fail to produce Driving Licence (No DL) ",
        "amount": 1200
      }
    ],
    "challan_status": [
      {
        "challan_status": "Cash",
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

I want to data in given format .
if challan_status is 'Cash' then

Offence name    Sum of amount

Valid Insurance Certificate produced during investigation   100

Fail to produce certificate of Fitness (No FC) or Plying Without Fitness Certificate    4000

Fail to produce Driving Licence (No DL) or Driving without effective DL     1200

I got below response when i tried to fetch data.

Offence name    Sum of amount

Valid Insurance Certificate produced during investigation   4300

Fail to produce certificate of Fitness (No FC) or Plying Without Fitness Certificate    4300

Fail to produce Driving Licence (No DL) or Driving without effective DL     4300

Comment: what is the query you are using?

Comment: {
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "challan_offences.offence_name.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 200
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "challan_offences.amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
 
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}

Comment: If it is related to query I added please post here or if it is another issue raise a seperate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change field "challan_offences" from object type to [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype
and use [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

Objects types are flattened out that is field "challan_offences" will be stored as

```
{
     challan_offences.offence_name="<sometext>",
     challan_offences.amount=100,
     challan_offences.offence_name="<sometext>",
     challan_offences.amount=4000,
     challan_offences.offence_name="<sometext>",
     challan_offences.amount=1200
}
```

so sum aggregation is  showing wrong values. By changing to nested type relation ship in offence_name and amount will be maintained

Mapping

```
PUT index70
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "challan_offences":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "offence_name":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
              "keyword":{
                "type":"keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "amount":{
            "type":"integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "challan_offences": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "challan_offences"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "offence_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "challan_offences.offence_name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "amount": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "challan_offences.amount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "challan_offences" : {
      "doc_count" : 3,
      "offence_name" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "Fail to produce Driving Licence (No DL) ",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "amount" : {
              "value" : 1200.0
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "Fail to produce certificate of Fitness",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "amount" : {
              "value" : 4000.0
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "Valid Insurance",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "amount" : {
              "value" : 100.0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks bro i have tested this and got required response. Now, I am trying it within application. Can i change mapping if it have huge data.

Comment: mapping cannot be changed, you will have to create index or use alias while deleting to preserve data